# Preview HTML markup inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor, markup

How to transform html codes within textarea while typing, as text editors do? I searched a lot, but preview is outside the textarea (which is very simple by jquery). I want to know the trick text editors do to display formatted html inside the textarea!

Note that I do not want a text editor, I want to show markeup when typping; for example displaying **BOLD** when typing `<b>BOLD</b>` inside textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textarea` does not have such a feature. However, you can still achieve the same effect with some Javascript acrobatics.

Check this out: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm

Comment: yes I know, and I want to know the basics of this javascript acrobatics ;)

Comment: you can view the source on that page, and stick it in a js beautifier. it is pretty complex and essentially involves handling keyboard events and building the display at every step.